# Why is xgboost returning a data type error in the data parameter?

Tags: r, xgboost, quantmod

I almost forked [this project from GitHub](https://github.com/amunategui/quantmod-wallstreet/blob/master/quantmod_wallstreet.R)

but in the [last script](https://github.com/amunategui/quantmod-wallstreet/blob/master/quantmod_wallstreet.R)

```
bst <- xgboost(data = as.matrix(train[,predictorNames]),
        label = train$outcome,
        verbose = 0,
        eta = 0.1,
        gamma = 50, 
        nround = 50,
        colsample_bytree = 0.1,
        subsample = 8.6,
        objective="binary:logistic")
predictions <- predict(bst, as.matrix(test[,predictorNames]), outputmargin=TRUE)
```

I get this error

> Error in xgb.DMatrix(data, label = label, missing = missing) : 'data'
> has class 'character' and length 1261520. 'data' accepts either a
> numeric matrix or a single filename.

but I've not been able to fix that. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

XGBoost cannot accept character data. You have forgotten something that is of character type in there. You need to either remove it or treat it somehow (one hot encoding for example)